# Dask map_blocks - IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-delayed

I want to do the following with Dask:

1. Load a matrix from a HDF5 file
2. Parallelize the calculation of each entry

Here is my code:

```
def blocked_func(x):
    return np.random.random()

with h5py.File(file_path) as f:
    d = f['/data']
    arr = da.from_array(d, chunks=(chunks_row, chunks_col))

    arr2 = arr.map_blocks(blocked_func, dtype='float32').compute()
```

But the code throws the following error:

```
File ".../remote_fr_thinkpad/test_big_data.py", line 43, in <module>
    arr2 = arr.map_blocks(blocked_func, dtype='float32').compute()
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 156, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 399, in compute
    return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 399, in <listcomp>
    return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 779, in finalize
    return concatenate3(results)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 3497, in concatenate3
    chunks = chunks_from_arrays(arrays)
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 3327, in chunks_from_arrays
    result.append(tuple([shape(deepfirst(a))[dim] for a in arrays]))
  File ".../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 3327, in <listcomp>
    result.append(tuple([shape(deepfirst(a))[dim] for a in arrays]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I googled around and also tried dask's gu_func, but that threw the same error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map_block` expects `blocked_func` to return an array of the same shape of its input `(chunks_row, chunks_col)`, while it actually just returns a float.

Try either with

1) a function which preserves shape, e.g:

```
def blocked_func(x):
    return x*2
```

or

2) tell `map_blocks` that the shape of the output will be different:

```
arr2 = arr.map_blocks(blocked_func, chunks=(1,1), dtype='float32').compute()
```

but keep the dimensionality of the input array in `blocked_func`, e.g.:

```
def blocked_func(x):
    return np.random.random()[None,None]
    # or like this
    # return np.array([1,1])
```